# Exception "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'"

Tags: firebase, exception, flutter, dart

I am trying to access values from a DocumentSnapshot which to the best of my knowledge returns a map. I then store the keys in the map to a list, from which I build a ListView. Then I try to access the values by using the keys in the map iteratively. Although I get my expected result and the UI is also rendered as required, the console logs an exception as follows.
`I/flutter ( 2093): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 2093): The following assertion was thrown building:
I/flutter ( 2093): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
I/flutter ( 2093): 
I/flutter ( 2093): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 2093): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 2093): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 2093):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 2093):
I/flutter ( 2093): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 2093): #0      _CartState.cartTile.<anonymous closure> (package:zombie/screens/home/nav/tabs/cart.dart:78:71)
I/flutter ( 2093): #1      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:446:15)
I/flutter ( 2093): #2      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1260:67)
I/flutter ( 2093): #3      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:139:29)
I/flutter ( 2093): #4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1260:26)
I/flutter ( 2093): #5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1273:55)
I/flutter ( 2093): #6      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2412:19)
I/flutter ( 2093): #7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1266:11)
I/flutter ( 2093): #8      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:354:23)
I/flutter ( 2093): #9      RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1823:58)
I/flutter ( 2093): #10     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:875:15)
I/flutter ( 2093): #11     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1823:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #12     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:343:5)
I/flutter ( 2093): #13     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:427:5)
I/flutter ( 2093): #14     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:78:12)
I/flutter ( 2093): #15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #16     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:134:11)
I/flutter ( 2093): #17     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:373:11)
I/flutter ( 2093): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #19     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:410:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #20     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1367:12)
I/flutter ( 2093): #21     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1285:20)
I/flutter ( 2093): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #25     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #31     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #43     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:259:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #45     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:744:15)
I/flutter ( 2093): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #47     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:206:11)
I/flutter ( 2093): #48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #49     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:163:11)
I/flutter ( 2093): #50     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:477:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #51     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:232:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #52     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:391:14)
I/flutter ( 2093): #53     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1584:7)
I/flutter ( 2093): #54     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
I/flutter ( 2093): #55     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:344:19)
I/flutter ( 2093): #56     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:774:13)
I/flutter ( 2093): #57     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
I/flutter ( 2093): #58     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
I/flutter ( 2093): #59     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
I/flutter ( 2093): #60     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
I/flutter ( 2093): #64     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)
I/flutter ( 2093): #65     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)
I/flutter ( 2093): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 2093): ════`

The following is a part of my code which causes the exception

```
Widget cartTile(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
var snap = doc.data;
if(snap == null){
  return SizedBox();
}
List<String> _keys = snap.keys.toList();
print(_keys);
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _keys.length,
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 3.0, 20.0, 3.0),
      child: Material(
          elevation: 10.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            onTap: () async {

            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10.0, 0),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snap[_keys[index]]['imgPath']),
                ),
```

Obviously the last line  `backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snap[_keys[index]]['imgPath']),` is the cause of exception. I've tried to solve it for hours but am not able to. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: use index.toString and let me know it is working or not?

Comment: How will that help ?? That won't even compile.. index needs to be in int.

Comment: What is the runtimeType of data stored at snap[_keys[index]] ?? May be it is Iterable/List and you are using it as a map.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is around "`['imgPath']`", have you tried to print only `snap[_keys[index]]` and sees if the output are a map? According the exception, seens to be a list to me...